# Error when running jar for context aware recommender

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to run the CARSKit software, downloaded the jar file (CARSKit-v0.2.0.jar) from here
https://github.com/irecsys/CARSKit

And followed the user guide that is here
 http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03780

The only thing that needs to be done apparently is to create a setting.CONF file to be placed at the same folder of the CARSKit.jar and also create the folders for the data and put the data there for example like this:
dataset.ratings.wins=C:\Data\DePaulMovie\ratings.txt

Then you are able to run it:
Run The Toolkit :
**java -jar CARSKit.jar -c setting.conf**

I tried the first one but got the following error and something similar if I try to run it using the other one:
java -jar CARSKit.jar -c CAMF.conf PMF.conf UserSplitting.conf

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, I had a problem with my java version